# jQuery Changing multiple ID's on cloned content

Tags: jquery, clone

I am currently cloning a specific row in a table, and appending it to the bottom (as well as clearing out any values in any input fields)

Like so:

```
$("#gn_Row_0").clone().find("input:text").val("").end().appendTo("#green_zone .medicine_table");
```

This has been working great so far..  however I noticed I need to also update the ID's on not only the main TR/row I am cloning but a nested SELECT and '2' ID's (2nd and 3rd) on nested TD's within this TR/row.

similar to this markup: (this whole markup is getting cloned and add to end of table)

```
<tr id="change this id 1">
    <td>
        <select id="change this id 2"></select>
    </td>

    <td id="change this id 3"></td>
    <td id="change this id 4"></td>
</tr>
```

I have tried altering my current line (just to see if I can update one of the ID's)

```
$("#gn_Row_0").clone().find("tr").prop('id', 'newID_here').end().find("input:text").val("").end().appendTo("#green_zone .medicine_table");
```

However I have not been successful.  How can I change ALL '4' id's in my cloned content?

**UPDATE:**

SORRY!

I figured it out.  I think the initial find() on the TR was making it now work, as that was the cloned ID

This is working for me:

```
$("#gn_Row_0").clone().prop('id', 'newID_here').find("select").prop('id', 'newID_here2').end().find("td:eq(1)").prop('id', 'newID_here3').end().find("td:eq(2)").prop('id', 'newID_here3').end().find("input:text").val("").end().appendTo("#green_zone .medicine_table");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend relying on simple HTML templating

Pesudo code:

template:

```
<script class="js-row-template" type="text/html">
    <tr id="change this {{id}}">
        <td>
            <select id="change this {{id}}"></select>
        </td>

        <td id="change this {{id}}"></td>
        <td id="change this {{id}}"></td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

code:

```
var template = $(".js-row-template").html();

var index = 0;

var model = {
    id: "id" + index,
    data: {
        // enter in extra data that you can pull from tr being cloned
    }
};

var templateMarkup = template.replace("{{id}}", model.id);

$(templateMarkup).appendTo("#green_zone .medicine_table");
```

This way, if the markup grows in complexity, you'll have to update the template, better yet, use 3rd party templating libraries like handlebars etc

Comment: The template is nice for a static design and updating some variables...  but as my cloned table cells have select boxes already populated by php/query calls.. it was either clone what was there (including all select/option elements).. or convert things to be a javascript array and populate the needed select/option content in those cloned rows.


@downvoter - care to speak up?